# Magento multistore: currency problem - Euro/Pounds?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Hope someone can help me with a currency problem. I have a multishop, Dutch and English. The Dutch store (default config) is in Euro's and I want to get the Englisch shop working in Pounds. The two shops are multishops with different root categories and when I try to put the English shop at Pounds: system/configuration/currency setup it won't work.

I put the display currency at pounds also with the frontend.

We are working with magento 1.4.0.1

Let me know if I do anything wrong?

Comment: Are they setup as actually sites or stores/views? From what I have gathered only a root based "site" as Magento refers to them as can change currency properly, at least in 1.4.x.

Answer (score 2):

The following link says how to set up multiple currency for Magento shop. It also describes how to set different currency for different store.

[Magento: Setup multiple currency shop](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-currency-shop/)

Hope this helps. Thanks.